# Can grails work with MySQL and MongoDB in the same application?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, grails

I am planning to write an application.  Some data I plan to place in a relational database, while others on MongoDB.  Is it possible to use both database in a single Grails application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is described here in the docs: http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.2%20Combining%20Mongo%20and%20Hibernate